# Need XsltContext when executing XPath query against specific element in document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to execute an XPath query against a specific, pre-selected element within a document. The element is attached to its document when the query is executed. This works fine for simple cases, but when attempting to use functions such as `current()` or `context()`, I get this error:

> XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function.

```
public string GetValue(XElement element, XmlNamespaceManager nsm) {
    object result = element.XPathEvaluate("(XPath query here)", nsm);

    // ...
}
```

Sample XPath:

```
//P:ConnectionInfo[@Name=current()/@ConnectionName]//P:Attribute[@Key='whatever']/@Value
```

In this example, the `current()` function is what causes the error to occur. I'm not sure how to provide more context for the XPath evaluation to succeed. I don't have any XSLT to compile as I'm not doing a transform in this case, just a simple XPath query.

*Using .NET 4.6*

Comment: `current()` is not an XPath function, it is only defined in XSLT. So there is no support for that in XPath. With XPath 3.0 you could use the path `let $outer-context := . return //P:ConnectionInfo[@Name=$outer-context/@ConnectionName]//P:Attribute[@Key='whatever']/@Value` but Microsoft does not even support XPath 2.0, only XPath 1.0.

Comment: If you want to set up variables in XPath evaluation in the Microsoft .NET XPath 1.0 implementation then I think you need to implement your on context, I think there was a `DynamicContext` class provided in http://sourceforge.net/projects/mvp-xml/files/Mvp.Xml/v2.0%20%28.NET%202.0%29/, you might want to check that to have a starting point.

Comment: A more up to date explanation and sample is provided at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is there any way to ask XPath "what is the node upon which the root of this query is executing"? E.g. `.` won't do it in a subquery since the context refers the the element upon which the subquery is executing. In this case I want the "root context" node.

Comment: The root node of the context node can be accessed with the path `/`. The context node can be accessed as `.` but the context node changes within predicates. That is why I showed the XPath 3.0 let expression as a pure XPath way. You would need to use an XPath 3.0 or XQuery implementation if you want to use that. In XPath 1.0 you need to set up a custom variable or function that gives you what you the node. How you can do that in the MS .NET environment is outlined in the samples respectively documents I linked to.